# Is there an easy way to get Android UI elements in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm developing a prototype of an Android app in HTML/CSS/JS, so that I can experiment with the UX of the app.

As a part of that I want to be able to style HTML elements as Android elements and (preferably) have them behave as if they're native Android UI elements.

Is there a JavaScript or CSS library that will do this for me? I've Googled, but nothing has come up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at the following Frameworks and Browserplugins. Maybe you will decide afterwards to regret using the native android toolkit at all, because it can be a big advantage to develop the application platform independent using HTML5 and Javascript techniques. Than later, if you want to port it to another platform you won't have to change a lot / almost nothing on the code base.

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

[Ripple Browser Plugin (Phone Emulator)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)

[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

which is completely themeable: [Jquery native android theme](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/)

The whole thing can finaly look like the following:

[jpHolo](http://www.teusink.org/blog/jpholo/)